# Maximum length of query string in PHP PDO SQLite?

Tags: php, sqlite

I'm trying to execute a (very long) query into an SQLite database using PHP (v8.0.5) PDO, but it seems like my query is being cut off when I call prepare().

Some snippets of my code are below:

```
$db = new SQLite3($SQLITE_DB_NAME);
$overall_query = 'SELECT DISTINCT presentations.Presentation_ID, presentations.Presentation_Name, presentations.Presentation_Type,
presentations.Presentation_File, presentations.Conference_ID,
GROUP_CONCAT(presentation_authors.Author_ID, ",") OVER 
(PARTITION BY presentation_authors.Presentation_ID ORDER BY presentation_authors.Author_Position ASC
 ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) AS Author_ID_List 
FROM presentations 
LEFT JOIN conferences ON conferences.Conference_ID=presentations.Conference_ID 
LEFT JOIN presentation_authors ON presentation_authors.Presentation_ID=presentations.Presentation_ID
WHERE 1 LIMIT :query_lim;';
```

...

```
$overall_query_prep = $db->prepare($overall_query);
```

When I `echo $overall_query;` and `print_r($overall_query);`, I get the full query as expected, and the query works on my SQLite database. However, I get an warning from PHP that says: `Warning: SQLite3::prepare(): Unable to prepare statement: 17, near &quot;(&quot;: syntax error in file.php on line 223`. This eventually results in a fatal error because it can't bind the values below.

Looking at the call stack in the warning, it looks like the variable was cut off when passing it to `prepare`. This is what the call stack shows (with ... to omit some repeated things):  `prepare( $query = 'SELECT DISTINCT ... ON conferences.Conference_ID=p' )`. The maximum length of what it sees appears to be fixed, as I tried shortening the statement and I see more of the query.

Is this just a result of how the call stack is shown or has PHP cut off my query somewhere? If so, why is it cutting it off?

Comment: `The maximum number of bytes in the text of an SQL statement is limited to SQLITE_MAX_SQL_LENGTH which defaults to 1,000,000,000.` - https://www.sqlite.org/limits.html so I doubt it is the length that is causing the issue. More likely a bad escape sequence of quotes or something like that.

Comment: It seems like this is going down the right path. When I make it arbitrarily long but remove the `OVER (...)` clause, it works fine. I think this specific question is solved-- PHP's stack log isn't showing my full query-- but my issue is now with the `OVER` clause, which works fine when querying the SQLite database directly, but not through PDO/PHP.

Comment: I have confirmed that it was a query error. I was trying out the query in a newer SQLite version than my docker PHP was running. Now that I have updated my instance to >3.25.0, my query works without issue.